# Stemming words ending with y

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to use Postgres' full text search, but I'm struggling to get certain query phrases working properly when stemming is involved.

strawberries matches strawberry

fruity does not match fruit

From what I've read these stemming algorithms are internal to Postgres and can't necessarily be modified easily. Does anyone know if the `-y` suffix can be stemmed properly?

Comment: Well, PostgreSQL allows for the writing of UDFs in other languages (Python, R, Java, etc), so you can always install an NLP library for the given language and write a UDF that will do the stemming.

Comment: If it helps, there are far less words ending in `ies` that can't be shortened to end in `y` than the other way around

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

I assume you are at least familiar with the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html) on the subject.  I think the simplest method would be to create a synonym dictionary with the pairs that are equivalent.

You need to be careful.  There are lots of words in English where you cannot remove the "y":

- lay <> la
- Gaily <> Gail (woman's name)
- Daily <> Dail (Irish parliament)
- foxy <> fox
- analog <> analogy

And this doesn't include the zillions of words where removing the "y" creates a non-word (a large class are -ly words; another, -way words).

You will need to manual create these yourselves.

I am not intimately familiar with Postgres's dictionaries.  But you should be able to accomplish what you want.